# Application is working on Android studio emulator but when it is downloaded from google play it stop unfortunately

Tags: android, apk, publish, android-install-apk

I create simple android studio application and published signed apk to google play store. The application was working fine on the emulator, it is a very simple app. so nothing should make it crash. Any way, after Google play store has published the app I downloaded it on my other mobiles. It open and displays all widgets. but when I click the button it crashes saying "Unfortunately Body Mass Index Calculator has stopped.
This is my third android app, and all of them are getting the same result. What am I doing wrong?. I am following all the instructions of publishing signed apk and I am following all google play store steps in a straight way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    tools:context="calculator.bodyweight.www.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/textView2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextweight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextweight"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:text="@string/textView3"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextweight"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextweight"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editTextHeight"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:onClick="calculate"
                android:text="@string/button"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/weight" />

        </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post your java file

Comment: Is there any crash log?

Comment: Are you using `ProGuard` for your release build?  If so, it might be you're missing some config for that.

Comment: No, I am not using proguard.

Comment: crash log: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
  at )

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error.
I was using methods for button click as public void(View view) { }, and that worked fine on debug versions on emulator and my mobile, but did not work on Release version. 
After I changed my method inside the oncreate tag, using the setOnclicklisner every thing worked fine on Release version and I uploaded it to the playstore, it is working perfectly. 
It was very hard to find this solution without guidance or clear log!. I am pasting it here for others who may find same problem.

Answer (score 0):

create new version from application and remove any previous data on your device, then test new apk again